# How can I run a systemd oneshot service outside the cgroup of this service?

Tags: systemd

I have a program which generates a bunch of images.  Although not really relevant, it is a Python program which spawns several other programs to get its job done.  It runs as a systemd unit.  When it is finished, it exits and I trust systemd at this point to ensure all of the processes involved get cleaned up, even if one of them has hung or is hanging around for some reason.

What I really want to do is, when the first service has completed, run a different systemd oneshot service which does the next part of the image processing job.  I want this to run entirely separately from the first service.  This second service will also start a bunch of processing tasks and again, I will be relying on systemd to clean up any spawned programs once the job is finished.

So how can I trigger the launch of the second systemd service *without it being part of the cgroup of the first*?  Put another way, without the second process being related at all to the first?

Comment: Why it has to be another service? Increasing the complexity of your software unnecessarily seems to be X-Y

Comment: Because the first service needs to get back to grabbing more images.  The second part of the image processing may be very time consuming, no need to prevent more images being grabbed.

Comment: But they are separate processes, they won't block each other. And in the question you said image processing start after first service completes, this is completely contradictory to your comments

Comment: I'm interested in the answer to my question, not questioning my architecture.